# Why did the Scala compiler get more strict regarding self types in 2.10?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, types, self, type-systems

I have the following code:

```
  trait TFn1B {
    type In
    type Out
    type Apply[T <: In] <: Out
  }

  trait TFn1[I, O] extends TFn1B {
    type In = I
    type Out = O
  }

  trait >>[F1 <: TFn1[_, _], F2 <: TFn1[_, _]] extends TFn1[F1#In, F2#Out] {
    type Apply[T] = F2#Apply[F1#Apply[T]]
  }
```

It compiles on Scala 2.9.1 without a warning or an error.

But on the current 2.10 build, I get the following error message:

```
Fun.scala:12: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type this.>>[F1,F2] does not conform to this.TFn1[_$1,_$4]'s selftype this.TFn1[_$1,_$4]
  trait >>[F1 <: TFn1[_, _], F2 <: TFn1[_, _]] extends TFn1[F1#In, F2#Out] {
                                                       ^
one error found
```

Is this a regression or is the code unsound and the compiler just started to catch it lately?
If the code is wrong, what would be a work-around to make it work again?

Comment: what happens if you leave `type Apply` abstract?

Comment: Does it make more sense to discuss this on SO than the Scala mailing lists given that 2.10 doesn't even have a release candidate yet?  This risks falling afoul of the "too localized in time" admonition.

Comment: I opened [SI-5402](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5402) about this.

Comment: Too lsow :-). See SI-5399, SI-5400.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug to me. There's no constraints on the type parameters of the super classes, but, more to the point, the trace for `-explaintypes` looks suspicious to me:

```
scala>   trait >>[F1 <: TFn1[_, _], F2 <: TFn1[_, _]] extends TFn1[F1#In, F2#Out] {
     |     type Apply[T] = F2#Apply[F1#Apply[T]]
     |   }
<console>:9: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type >>[F1,F2] does not conform to TFn1[_$1,_$4]'s selftype TFn1[_$1,_$4]
         trait >>[F1 <: TFn1[_, _], F2 <: TFn1[_, _]] extends TFn1[F1#In, F2#Out] {
                                                              ^
>>[F1,F2] <: TFn1[_$1,_$4]?
  TFn1[_$1,_$4] <: TFn1[_$1,_$4]?
    _$1 <: _$1?
      _$1 <: Nothing?
        <notype> <: Nothing?
        false
        Any <: Nothing?
          <notype> <: Nothing?
          false
        false
      false
      Any <: _$1?
        Any <: Nothing?
          <notype> <: Nothing?
          false
        false
      false
    false
  false
false
```

Specifically, I don't understand how or why it cannot prove that `TFn1[_$1,_$4] <: TFn1[_$1,_$4]` or even `_$1 <: _$1`.

Answer (score 3):

As seen on the Scala mailing list (posted by you), [Paul Phillips answers](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala/25368) that:

> It's already open ([SI-5399](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5399), [SI-5400](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5400)).
>   The regression arises from attempts to address [SI-5120: rather spectacular soundness failure with abstract types](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5120).

Potential problematic commits:

- [22d125f1e3: Trying to fix sdt core build.](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/22d125f1e3)
- [2e092d4822: Fix for problem in SBT that was caused by the too severe fix of type …](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/2e092d4822d044312317c502badd8ad5c2674b58)